# a new proof of a square matrix is similar to its transpose (not completed)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know there exist a classical way to prove that a square matrix is similar to its transpose in $C$ using jordan matrices.

I would like to prove it in another way but i have  some difficulities to overcome.

Here is my proof.

First, the result is trivial for a diagonalisable matrix. One only need to take the transpose of the transformation matrix.

now we want to prove the case when our matrix $M$ is not diagonalisable.
It is known that the set of diagonalisable matrices is in fact dense in the space $M_{C}(n \times n)$. Therefore, there exist a sequence of diagonalisable $M_{n}$ that converges to $M$. We know $M_n$ are all similar to their transpose which means $P_{n}^{-1}M_n P_{n}=M_{n}^{T}$.

As $M_n$ converge to $M$, $M_{n}^{T}$ converge to $M^{T}$. Now the only problem remains is to find a convergent sub-sequence of $P_n$ that converges to a invertible matrix $P$. Then we prove $PMP^{-1}=M^{T}$.

In fact, by setting an upper bound of $||P_n||$ and the théoreme of Bolzano-Weierstrass one can prove that there exist a convergent sub-sequence of $P_n$. The problem is this sub-sequence could converge to a singular matrix. I can not set an upper bound of $||P_n||$ and a lower bound of $det(P_n)$ at the same time.

It seems my proof goes to a dead end from there. Anyone get some idea?
.

Comment: You can also use the Zariski topology on the set of matrices. These spaces are compact.

Comment: @JohannesHahn compact but not Hausdorff. How do you want to use compactness? most sequences converge to all points.

Comment: @YCor: I want to use compactness to show that the projection of $\{(M,P) | MP = M^T P\}\subseteq K^{n\times n}\times GL_n(K)$ onto the first component is closed.

Comment: @JohannesHahn compactness passes to images, but (compact $\Rightarrow$ closed) is a Hausdorff phenomenon. This approach sounds hopeless.

Comment: @YCor But $X$ compact $\iff \forall Y: \pi_Y : X\times Y\to Y$ closed.

Comment: @JohannesHahn The Zariski topology on $X\times Y$ is not the product of Zariski topologies. Precisely, your subset of a product is not closed in the product of Zariski topologies.